# pie chart with ggplot2 with specific order and percentage annotations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like below

```
+--------+-----------+-----+
|  make  |   model   | cnt |
+--------+-----------+-----+
| toyota |  camry    |  10 |
| toyota |  corolla  |   4 |
| honda  |  city     |   8 |
| honda  |  accord   |  13 |
| jeep   |  compass  |   3 |
| jeep   |  wrangler |   5 |
| jeep   |  renegade |   1 |
| accura |  x1       |   2 |
| accura |  x3       |   1 |
+--------+-----------+-----+
```

I need to create a pie ( yes really) of the percentage share for each make.

I do the following as of now.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Make=c('toyota','toyota','honda','honda','jeep','jeep','jeep','accura','accura'),
                 Model=c('camry','corolla','city','accord','compass', 'wrangler','renegade','x1', 'x3'),
                 Cnt=c(10, 4, 8, 13, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1))
dfc <- df %>%
  group_by(Make) %>%
  summarise(volume = sum(Cnt)) %>%
  mutate(share=volume/sum(volume)*100.0) %>%
  arrange(desc(volume))

bp <- ggplot(dfc[c(1:10),], aes(x="", y= share, fill=Make)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
pie <- bp + coord_polar("y")
pie
```

This gives me the following pie chart which is pretty neat.

[image]

However I need to enhance this with the following things - like in the image below.

1. add percentage labels
2. order the pies in desc order of `share`
3. remove lables like 0/100, 25
4. add a title

[image]

Comment: to 2. set `levels` of `factor(share)` according to the order you like. 4. duplicated question.

Comment: 3. work with `geom_text` to get what you want where you want. Google "piechart r" -> images -> click on the image of a piechart you like. There is probably code you can use.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to change levels of `Make` by `share` or `volume` (provided data is already sorted):

```
dfc$Make <- factor(dfc$Make, levels = rev(as.character(dfc$Make)))
```

And play with `theme` arguments:

```
ggplot(dfc[1:10, ], aes("", share, fill = Make)) +
    geom_bar(width = 1, size = 1, color = "white", stat = "identity") +
    coord_polar("y") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(share), "%")), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, 
         title = "market share") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ffd700", "#bcbcbc", "#ffa500", "#254290")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! How would you increase the size of the percentage labels?

Comment: @Microscone change size within `geom_text`. For example: `geom_text(size = 10, ...)`

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Make) %>%
  summarise(volume = sum(Cnt)) %>%
  mutate(share=volume/sum(volume)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y= share, fill=reorder(Make, volume))) +
   geom_col() +
   geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round(share,3))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
   coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
   theme_void()
```

[image]

add `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))` for a reversed legend

Comment: The order of the pies need to be in the same order of share % - so Honda shall come first in the pie.