# Add % labels to pie chart ggplot2 after specifying factor orders

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, factors, ggtext

I have a data frame from which I want to make a pie chart that shows the % label

Here's what I did first

```
SubSegment<- c('S1','S2','S3','S4')
v <- c(100, 300, 500, 200)
df<- cbind.data.frame(SubSegment, v)

#calculations for % labels in chart
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(SubSegment)) %>%
  mutate(prop = v / sum(df$v)) %>%
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(prop)- 0.5*prop ) %>%
  mutate(label= prop*1)
df[5] = sapply(df[5], function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 0.1))

plot.ex <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = SubSegment)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color="white", alpha=0.8) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = label), size=3, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

The result:
[image]

As you can see, the labels look great and they are on the right place but it bothers me that the order of the factors is alphabetical, I would want the company with the biggest value to show first in the legend so I added one line of code before the plot:

```
df$SubSegment <- factor(df$SubSegment, levels=df$SubSegment[order(-(df$prop))], ordered=TRUE)
```

After doing that the order of the factors in the legend of the plot is as I wanted but the labels get all messed up (they don't move accordingly with the pie pieces).

Here's what my second pie chart looks like:
[image]

Basically I want to know how to edit my *ypos* line so that the labels will move accordingly when the pie pieces move.

Comment: Try `pie(df$v, col=2:5, labels=paste0(round(proportions(df$v)*100, 1), '%'));legend('right', col=2:5, leg=df$SubSegment, pch=15)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pie chart with ggplot2 with specific order and percentage annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752037/pie-chart-with-ggplot2-with-specific-order-and-percentage-annotations)

Answer (score 1):

You want to show the subsegments based on their proportions and therefore should calculate your `ypos` based on your proporations. This can be simply done by changing your `arrange()` line:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(prop = v / sum(df$v), 
         label= scales::percent(prop, accuracy = 0.1)) %>% 
  arrange(prop) %>% 
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(prop)- 0.5*prop, 
         SubSegment = factor(SubSegment, levels=SubSegment[order(-(prop))], ordered=TRUE))



ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = SubSegment)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color="white", alpha=0.8) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = label), size=3, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image: pie chart]