# How to reorder arrangement of slices in a pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a pie chart that's representing the amount of pollution from a given year from different industry sectors. This is from a public EPA dataset. Since there are many industry sectors, I don't want to include all of them, and want to include a lump "other" category. However, I don't want this category showing up in the middle of the chart, even though it is larger than some of the smaller slivers. I'd rather it be at the end. Any idea how to fix? Thanks.

```
group_by(tri1987tce, IndSec) %>% 
  summarize(amt=sum(`61. ON-SITE RELEASE TOTAL`)/1000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=amt, fill=reorder(IndSec, amt))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752037/pie-chart-with-ggplot2-with-specific-order-and-percentage-annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forcats::fct_relevel` to move a factor level to the last position.

```
fill = forcats::fct_relevel(reorder(IndSec, amt), "Other", after = Inf)
```